# Angularjs - How to check undefined from select value

Tags: angularjs

How to check or to trap the `undefined` select value from the select tag.
This is to prevent the user forget the select from the selection box.

Have been trying as below JS but it still show undefined error in the console log and not alert is show in browser.

**CODE**

```
<select ng-model="add.partcode" ng-options="x.part_no for x in DistictPartCode" ng-change="Getlocation()">
    <option value="">Please select partcode</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
if(!angular.isUndefinedOrNull($scope.add.partcode.part_no )){
    var Partcode = $scope.add.partcode.part_no;
  }else {
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Error ...',
      template: 'Please choose your part code first.'
    });
  }
```

**OR**

```
if(!$scope.add.partcode.part_no){
    var Partcode = $scope.add.partcode.part_no;
  }else {
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Error ...',
      template: 'Please choose your part code first.'
    });
  }
```

Error in console.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'part_no' of undefined`

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: update the question, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's becuse `$scope.add.partcode` become object when any object is selected otherwise it's just a `null` and `null` don't have property to access them using `.`

Try like this

```
if (!$scope.add.partcode) {
  var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: 'Error ...',
    template: 'Please choose your part code first.'
  });
} else {
  var Partcode = $scope.add.partcode.part_no;
}
```